SCD 2 implementation in Postgres or SQL Server | how to avoid duplicates & update old record
I am new to data warehouse.
I am tiring to implement SCD 2 using date method. I have struck to implement.
**OLTP table **
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    CustomerID int PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    Phone VARCHAR(20)
); 

OLAP TABLE
CREATE TABLE Customer_Dim 
(
    CustomerDimID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, -- Surrogate key column
    CustomerID INT,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    LastName VARCHAR(50),
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    Phone VARCHAR(20),
    EffectiveDate DATE,
    EndDate DATE
);

Questions

How to avoid duplicate records (when insert the records again it also added) ?
If the same record (customer ID for identification) come (assume in this record i have changed the phone number) then old record the end date is need to be updated to current date.

Expected results

first insert (default value - "9999-12-31" for "EndDate"
CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, EffectiveDate, EndDate
1   1   "John"  "Doe"   "john@example.com"  "193-456-7890"  "2024-04-19"    "9999-12-31"

second insert (phone column value changed)
CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, EffectiveDate, EndDate
1   1   "John"  "Doe"   "john@example.com"  "193-456-7890"  "2024-04-19"    "2024-04-19"  (old record)
1   1   "John"  "Doe"   "john@example.com"  "123-456-7890"  "2024-04-19"    "9999-12-31" (new record)


please share your answers 

You have to define what is a duplicate in your table Customer_Dim. Please give at least one concrete example. Then you add a CONSTRAINT UNIQUE in your table definition in order to avoid these duplicates. You can update the old record with a trigger on  INSERT.
